# Is there benefit to adding a document identifier in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, collections, document

I'm using mongodb to store test data. There will be 3 types of documents that will be created test case, test run, and the test data.

Test data will contain keys called testrun_id and testcase_id that will be used as a two way reference for information on test data.

I was wondering if it was worth adding a key in each of type of documents that specifies the type of document it is.

For example:

```
{
    _id : ObjectID(testdata ID),
    testcase_id : ObjectID(testcase ID),
    testrun_id :  ObjectID(testrun ID),
    docType : "3",
    data1 : 1234,
    data2 : 5678
}
// Another document
{
    _id : ObjectID(testdata ID 2),
    testcase_id : ObjectID(testcase ID),
    testrun_id :  ObjectID(testrun ID),
    docType : "3",
    data1 : 1234,
    data2 : 5678
}
```

Where docType could be 1 for test case, 2 for test run, and 3 for test data.

I would think this would help grab all specific types of document quicker? Or does MongoDB have a functionality like this already?

Comment: Hard to comment on without more context. But why not keep the three types of documents in three separate collections?

Answer (score 0):

Document (_id) identifier will be generated by mongodb database driver.

Incase you want to override it, you can send it from your application while creating a document.

It also ensures a unique identifier assigned to every document in a collection and is not null, means it is primary key for the document.

In your case if you have testcase_id as a unique id, you can send it in _id, but make sure it is always unique and not null.

For more information you can see this link:
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb